# What is the proper way to implement user permissions in the filter in a java web app using MVC?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, model-view-controller, user-permissions

What is the proper way to implement user permissions in the filter in a java web app using MVC?

All my jsp files are located in the directory `WEB-INF`.

All requests are processed in a Servlet (you have to send a request by a GET or POST query calling

```
get-->/controller?command=particularcommand
```

using POST you need to specify the command parameter in another way).

So access to them is performed by commands. Also commands are used to perform other operations.

I have 4 types of  users and 2 enums containing names of commands (Ajax and usual). I use command pattern and command factory.

So the main idea of the question is what is the proper way to organize permissions in the filter - collections or xml files or smth else.

BTW, the idea is not to use any frameworks. Only jsp can be used. That's the resctriction of my task.

Answer (score 0):

[Filter or intercepting Filter](http://www.developer.com/security/article.php/3467801/Securing-J2EE-Applications-with-a-Servlet-Filter.htm) is a very good idea to check the request permission. It is also the proper way. Just redirect to main page or send *401* error if permission is not granted.

Anyway i suggest you to use modern frameworks like [Spring MVC](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/) with [Spring security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/) and other great features.

Comment: thks for your answer, but i can not use frameworks, that's the restriction of my task. I want to find out what is the proper way to organize permissions in java in the filter without frameworks.

Comment: SO just implement the Filter and add it in your web.xml

Comment: Yes, I understand I know, but how to implement it in the filter? See my corrected question.